# How can I automate a google link on the page I am working on using watir-webdriver?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

Page link I am working on is http://www.whatcar.com/car-news/subaru-xv-review/260397

I am trying to automate 'clicking the google link' but am having no luck and keep receiving an error.

Link HTML:

```
<a tabindex="0" role="button" title="" class="s5 JF Uu" id="button" href="javascript:void(0);" aria-pressed="false" aria-label="Click here to publicly +1 this."></a>
```

My code:

```
@browser.link(:class, "s5 JF Uu").click
```

Error message:

```
unable to locate element, using {:class=>"s5 JF Uu", :tag_name=>"a"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
./step_definitions/11.rb:12:in `/^On the page I click 'Twitter' , Facebook and Google button$/'
11.feature:8:in `When On the page I click 'Twitter' , Facebook and Google+ button'
```

Comment: I know how to click the link, but until you let us know if you are creating a spam bot, I will keep the answer to myself.

Comment: If we believe his profile, He's a QA engineer working for the company that makes that site.  He's also clearly using cucumber, which is not something I'd expect from a spammer.  I think we're safe to presume he's legit.. but of course if I got an email to sqapro on my gmail then I'd be even more comfortable ;-)

Comment: Even if he works for the site in question, he's bumping up their articles via social media sites.  Google tests their buttons already.

Comment: The site should add a robots.txt.

Comment: @DaveMcNulla: watir script will ignore robots.txt, like any other misbehaving robot :)

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden: I will wait until we hear from him/her

Comment: Err first off I am not a spammer. Secondly I am a him and do work for the company in question. Also I am not bumping up any articles (why would I do that? I already have enough on my plate ;))and thirdly I am fairly new to the automation side of things (as you probably have noticed) and just need a little assistance. In my Gherkin script I had added that I checked to make sure the Google widget was clickable, hence I have been going crazy trying to automate the google widget to click:( Any help would be very much appreciated as you guys are way more learned in watir-webdriver, ruby than I am.

Comment: @Azher: you would be surprised how many times we see spammers asking watir relate questions. Since you said you are not spammer, I have provided my answer.

Comment: Many thanks Zeljko, I will give it a go. I can completely understand your concern and can re-assure you I'm just a QA trying to learn. Will get back to you if i'm successful.

Comment: @Zeljko: I know that Watir doesn't check robot.txt but a responsible person would always look for that to see what restrictions the site has. They are easy to read. That in itself does not guarantee moral behavior but it's a first start.

Comment: I think the fact that watir was designed as a TEST tool to emulate user actions, and not a robot probably has a lot to do with why it doesn't pay any attention to robots.txt (since 99.9% of humans have no idea what that file is or does).   OTOH if you are using watir to crawl/scrape etc other people's sites I'd agree your script should be checking the robots file and abiding by it.  (and you should also review user agreements, terms of service, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link is inside a frame. To make it even more fun, frame `id` is different every time the page is refreshed.

```
browser.frames.collect {|frame| frame.id}
=> ["I1_1323429988509", "f3593c4f374d896", "f4a5e09c20624c", "stSegmentFrame", "stLframe"] 

browser.refresh
=> [] 

browser.frames.collect {|frame| frame.id}
=> ["I1_1323430025052", "fccfdf9410ef34", "f11036dad706668", "stSegmentFrame", "stLframe"]
```

`I1_1323429988509` and `I1_1323430025052` is the frame. Since `I1_` part is always the same, and no other frame has that, you can access the frame like this:

```
browser.frame(:id => /I1_/)
```

Since there is only one link inside the frame:

```
browser.frame(:id => /I1_/).as.size
=> 1
```

You can click the link like this:

```
browser.frame(:id => /I1_/).a.click
```

Or if you prefer to be more explicit

```
browser.frame(:id => /I1_/).a(:id => "button").click
```

That will open a new browser window, and a new challenge is here! :)

Comment: was it just a single frame?  or  NESTED frames?  just so much fun..  I normally tend to give devs grief about frames being 'web 1.0', but one valid use for them is when you are providing what amounts to a window to code at another site. in that case containing code from some other source inside a frame tends to make sense (at least IMHO anyway)

Answer (score 1):

**The technical answer:**
The class of the button on the page that you linked is different for me than the class that you list.  It looks like it behaves differently based on the cookies on your local machine (which would be absent during a Watir-driven Firefox or IE session).

You would need to find a different element that is not dynamic to hook into.

**The ethical answer:**
It is questionable that you are attempting to automate the promotion of online articles through social media.  Watir/Watir-Webdriver is not a spam bot, and the services you are using specifically prohibit the use of automation/bots.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for your answer. I promise my intentions were straight forward as all I intended to do was to show that the widget existed on the page. Looks like I need to make changes in my Gherkin scripts

Comment: Glad to hear it Azher.  We don't assume you're trying to do something nefarious, but it's important to note it for others.

Answer (score 1):

That 'button' link is inside an iframe.   Read on the watir Wiki [how to deal with stuff in frames](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Frames).  If that's not enough to get it working please edit the answer with revised code and error etc and we can work it forward from that point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chuck, but I guess the best thing to do here would be to edit my gherkin scripts and not include the widgets at all, due to the security implication :)

Comment: Or test that they are present, and have the proper URL's etc..  beyond that you cross the boundary into testing the browser and someone elses site, which provides little value to your employer.